# MySQL, json, JSON_ARRAY_APPEND - why will append not work on 5.7.13?

Tags: mysql, json

How on earth do I insert data into a json mysql field.

I can create a record

```
INSERT INTO git_object (user_id,git_meta,last_update) VALUES ('11111','[{"host": "a", "id": "1"}]',(select now()));
```

How do I append to the array.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', '{"host": "b"}') FROM git_object where user_id='11111'
```

I tried the above.  What do I get with the below?

```
SELECT * FROM git_object;

'[{"id": "1", "host": "a"}]'
```

What am I doing wrong

MySQL Version '5.7.13'

Comment: The 2nd query is a select, no modifications to the underlying data is done. What exactly do you want to achive?

Comment: I want to modify.  Append to the json object stored in the table.

Comment: To modify the data you need an update sql command, not a select. The same command you would use to update any field.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To modify data stored in any table you need to use the `update` sql command, not select.

```
Update git_object
set  git_meta=JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', '{"host": "b"}')
where user_id='11111'
```

Answer (score 17):

Use `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', JSON_OBJECT('host','b'))`

instead of `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', '{"host": "b"}')`

Comment: here is the reference for JSON_OBJECT
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object

Comment: Thanks, my issue was that `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(git_meta, '$', '{"host": "b"}')` would append a string instead of a json object. Using `JSON_OBJECT` works.

Comment: Perfect, I was looking for exactly this JSON_OBJECT() solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'cast' to do so.

```
JSON_ARRAY_APPEND('[]', '$', CAST('{"host": "b"}' as JSON));
```