# Append array to JSON column to multiple rows at once

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a column type JSON in database, and I'm performing an update on multiple rows.

For example, this query

```
Model::whereIn('id',$ids)->update([
   'status' => 'canceled'
]);
```

And this table has another column called history (JSON type), each row already has its own history in JSON.

How do I append to each one of them? This array, for example

```
[
   'user_id' => '144',
   'action'  => 'cancel',
   'at'      => '2021 - 08 - 30'
]
```

My idea and question, is there something like

```
Model::whereIn( 'id', $ids )->appendJson('field_name',$array);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest approach could be like this:

```php
$status = 'canceled';
$extraHistoryData = [...];

Model::whereKey($ids)->get(function ($model) use ($status, $extraHistoryData) {
    $history = $model->history;

    $history = array_merge($history, $extraHistoryData);

    $model->update(compact('status', 'history'));
});
```

If you want to update all rows in a single query, the closest I can get is this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694213/mysql-json-json-array-append-why-will-append-not-work-on-5-7-13). But It's not very likely to solve your problem.