# How to properly insert/get Array of json Objects into myslq with laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

frankly speaking this is my first time working with Json Array in Mysql and Laravel. I have spent a day try to figure this out without a success.
After inserting data into the database, the data looks like is not a well Json array object, I have try to encode and decode when inserting and getting the data respectively but the result does not look like a proper array.
Below is the model class

```
 class SmsModel extends Model
  {     
   protected $fillable = [..'sms'..];
   protected function sms(): Attribute
   {
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => json_decode($value, true),
        set: fn ($value) => json_encode($value),
     );
   } }
```

migration file

```
  ...public function up()
   {
    Schema::create('parcel_infos', function (Blueprint $table) {
       ......
        $table->json('sms')->nullable();
       .......
     }); 
   }...
```

below is the controller

```
  $smsText = '[
        { "id": 1, "sentBy": "Hardik", "sms": "Mambo vipi"},
        { "id": 2, "sentBy": "Vimal", "sms": "Poa sana"},
        { "id": 3, "sentBy": "Harshad", "sms": "Karibu kwetu"}
    ]';
 $data = json_encode($smsText, true);
  $input = [
        ......
        'sms' => $data
        .......
     ];
 SmsModel::create($input);
```

When fetching the data I am receiving the below output even even after decode it with json_decode().

```
  [{"sms":"\"\\\"[\\\\n            { \\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\": 1, \\\\\\\"sentBy\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Hardik\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"sms\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Mambo vipi\\\\\\\"},\\\\n            { \\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\": 2, \\\\\\\"sentBy\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Vimal\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"sms\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Poa sana\\\\\\\"},\\\\n            { \\\\\\\"id\\\\\\\": 3, \\\\\\\"sentBy\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Harshad\\\\\\\", \\\\\\\"sms\\\\\\\": \\\\\\\"Karibu kwetu\\\\\\\"}\\\\n        ]\\\"\""}]
```

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: $table->json('sms')->nullable(); json columns need casting into array so that you can fetch data back https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: @Sumitkumar I have just added  `protected $casts = [ 'sms' => 'array']; `and removed the `Attribute` and the model but it doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your model (SmsModel) :

```
protected $casts = [
    'sms' => 'array'
];
```

Then in your controller (for create/insert):

```
$smsText = '[
        { "id": 1, "sentBy": "Hardik", "sms": "Mambo vipi"},
        { "id": 2, "sentBy": "Vimal", "sms": "Poa sana"},
        { "id": 3, "sentBy": "Harshad", "sms": "Karibu kwetu"}
]';
$input = [
       'sms' => $smsText
];
SmsModel::create($input);
```

then to fetch back sms's =>

```
$all = SmsModel::find($someID);
$data = json_decode($all->sms, true);
```

**OR A BETTER APPROACH**

since we've casted that column json => array we can simply push arrays into the column and laravel casts will do the thing:

```
$smsText = array(
        [
            "id" => 1,
            "sentBy" => "Hardik",
            "sms" => "Mambo vipi"
        ], 
        [
            "id" => 2,
            "sentBy" => "Vimal",
            "sms" => "Poa sana"
        ], 
        [
            "id" => 3,
            "sentBy" => "Harshad",
            "sms" => "Karibu kwetu"
        ]
    );
$input = [
            'sms' => $smsText
    ];
SmsModel::create($input);
```

and to fetch back sms :

```
$find = SmsModel::find(5);
dd($find->sms); //will return array of sms's
```

Comment: this works perfectly, one more question, What if I want to add/update the created array with the new data. Thanks a lot

Comment: do look into this for updating json : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#updating-json-columns do mark answer if solved

Comment: Actually I want to insert a new object into the created array.

Comment: I had to use `JSON_ARRAY_APPEND( )` with native mysql code. This link solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/39685058/10412027 . Thank you so much @Sumit kumar